# React Component updating itself

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project. one of the component is updating its state itself. I am new to react, can anybody help me to fix this issue ?

```
class NumberOfEvents extends Component {
  state = {
    eventCount: 5,
  };

  handleEventInputChanged = (event) => {
    const eventCount = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      eventCount,
    });
    this.props.updateEvents("", eventCount);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="event-number">
        <label htmlFor="numberOfEvent"></label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="numberOfEvent"
          className="event-number-input"
          placeholder="Enter Number of Events"
          value={this.state.eventCount}
          onChange={this.handleEventInputChanged}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NumberOfEvents;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "component updating itself"?

Comment: Because you have used `updateEvents` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to update the state using the input do:

```js
export default class NumberOfEvents extends Component {
  state = {
    eventCount: 5,
  };

  handleEventInputChanged = (event) => {
    const eventCount = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      eventCount
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="event-number">
        <label htmlFor="numberOfEvent">{this.state.eventCount}</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="numberOfEvent"
          className="event-number-input"
          placeholder="Enter Number of Events"
          value={this.state.eventCount}
          onChange={this.handleEventInputChanged}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Object shorthand is valid syntax, i.e. `this.setState({ eventCount });` is acceptable.